# What does Bell mean by polarization of spin state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

I am reading John Bell's article [On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen paradox](https://journals.aps.org/ppf/abstract/10.1103/PhysicsPhysiqueFizika.1.195) and I am confused by the following sentence in the beginning of part III:

> Suppose we have a spin half particle in a pure spin state with polarization denoted by a unit vector ...

What does Bell mean by polarization of spin $\tfrac12$ state?

Comment: Spin has a direction. If spin is polarized it just means the spin points along a particular direction.

Comment: @josephh how spin can be not polarized?

Comment: Because you need a direction _along_ with the spin orientation. You cannot say that because a particle has spin direction, then it's automatically polarized. In this instance, the particle spin is polarized along the direction denoted by the unit vector.

Comment: @josephh Well, you confused things completely. What is spin orientation? Spin can be measured along any orientation. How it differs from spin polarization?

Comment: No, I haven't. You missed my point about needing a specific direction. I suggest you have a read of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_polarization).

Comment: The particles are prepared in such a way that a spin measurement will always reveal a spin parallel to the unit vector. This is called "polarization."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The space of states of a spin-1/2 object is the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), which, as the name implies, can be viewed as the two-sphere $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Every point of the sphere corresponds to a unit vector $\hat{n}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, and the state corresponding to it is an eigenstate of the spin operator $S_{\hat{n}}$ that measures the spin in that direction. This $\hat{n}$ is the "polarization vector".

Comment: I guess you are correct, there are no other directions in 3D for spin-1/2 than directions on the Bloch sphere. I'm still confused what is spin polarization for other spin values but I did not ask it. Hopefully your answer pushed me in right direction.

Answer (score 3):

A spin 1/2 state can be projected on an axis as +1/2 or -1/2, it is an angular momentum vector with its units. Bell wants a unit-less vector, to denote the direction of spin as + or -1, and calls it the polarization vector .

Comment: I've no problems with 1 vs 1/2: Bell uses Pauli matrices instead of spin operators. What confuses me is the word *polarization*. I guess it is a direction where a particle has spin eigenvalues, that is spin of a particle is predetermined.

Comment: the **direction** of the spin is given by the polarization vector.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what is spin direction or spin polarization vector. To my knowledge, spin can be measured in any direction.

Comment: Spin is angular momentum and it adds up to the angular momentum of a system. Angular momentum is a vector, Vectors https://www.britannica.com/science/vector-physics